# How to parse a mixed single and multiple lines text?

Tags: python, regex, csv, subprocess

I want to query the tasks information from a CM synergy database.
I use these python script snippet:

```
cmd = "ccm task -query -release " + release_name + \
        " -format \"%displayname; %task_synopsis; %task_description; %owner; %completion_date; %status\""
    (status, output) = subprocess.getstatusoutput(cmd)
print("status: {}".format(status))
print("output: \n{}".format(output))
```

Then I get these following like output text in which there are multiple lines in the third column:

```
1179836; Development projects dev/1.0;      Init tools                                              yangli; 3/29/17 4:05 PM;  completed
                                            Result: no
                                            Comment: This is a testing review comment, it's ok.;
```

Then How can I parse them into a .csv format file?
   I want to know how can I get the completed third column which have many lines.
   Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: This is not CSV. CSV does support embedded newlines, but in a different way. I suspect you'll have to write a full-blown custom parser that tracks indentation levels and joins the 'columns' in a tree-like structure.

Comment: You asked for several semicolon delimited fields. It makes sense to do `[item.strip() for item in output.split(';')]`. That produces data for a set of query fields, some of which happen to have newlines in them. The strange thing is, they don't seem to match up with the fields given in `-format`. Are you sure that command produced the output?

Comment: If all you want is the third column, that's all you should ask for in -format.